# $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{12^k}{(4^{k+1}-3^{k+1})(4^k-3^k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to break the 12^k part to (4^k)(3^k) and then divided numerator and denominator with it...i didnt work...i tried everything that came to my mind..please help me with this summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{12^k}{(4^{k+1}-3^{k+1})(4^k-3^k)}$$